# Run golang online and save it to an online file

Tags: go

What my local program does right now is connect to a websocket and updates a local file with a json whenever a message is received.

Is there a way to run the golang program online and then update and save the file as a json file online that I will be able to see? I'm not sure but I think I would need a web server?

For example, the program would generate a website like this https://www.reddit.com/r/all.json ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically most websites generate JSON responses directly into the HTTP request, they don't write the results into a file that is then served over HTTP.

You will need some kind of server that is exposed to the Internet either way. I would recommend you reading about how to use the HTTP server built into Go, so you don't need to write the results into a file: https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/. Once you gain a better understand on how web applications work, you can use higher level web frameworks that can help you be more productive, such as gin: https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin.

If you would still really like to write the results in a file and serve that file, you may as well use Go as the web server, and use https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile.

Example code of doing this:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/myfile.json", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "path/to/myfile.json")
    })

    // Serve on HTTP port (80)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm still new to this so I didn't know how other websites did it. The documents you linked look really helpful and I will start reading them now.